# Theming Form Fields: Alter all fields

Tags: 7, forms, theming

In Drupal 7, you can put the following code in template.php to add the class 'vr-paragraphs' to the field called 'field_title'

```
function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
       $form['field_title']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'vr-paragraphs';
}
```

How can I modify this code to target all fields on the form and not just 'field_title'.

Also, this code only adds the class to the form-wrapper part of the filed. How can I alter the label part?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to find the child items present in a form, you need to use [element_children()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/element_children/7), as Drupal functions like [filter_process_format()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_process_format/7) do.

The reason is simple: In a Drupal form array, as well as in a render array, not all the keys are child items; those keys with a name that starts with # are properties. Consider, for example, the form returned from [forum_form_forum()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum.admin.inc/function/forum_form_forum/7); if you loop through it with the following code, you would add values where you should not.

```
foreach($form as $key => $value) {
  $form[$key]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'vr-paragraphs';
}
```

In fact, `$form['#submit']` is not a child item, nor is `$form['#theme']`. In particular, when your code will be executed for the last key, you would get a PHP error. `$form['#theme']` is a string, and `$form['#theme']['#attributes']` would select a character of that string, supposing that `'#attributes'` would be evaluated as the integer 0; even in that case, `$form['#theme']['#attributes']['class'][]` would not be a valid PHP construct.

The correct code would be the following one.

```
foreach(element_children($form) as $key) {
  $form[$key]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'vr-paragraphs';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement a for loop over each form field to add the class.
eg.

```
foreach(form as $key => $value){
  $form[$key]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'vr-paragraphs';
}
```

You may have to check if it is actually a field though, maybe by checking if `$form[$key]['#title']` is set.

If I remember correctly, the label is usually taken from the '#title' of the field.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I have tried:  `function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
foreach(form as $key => $value){
  $form[$key]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'vr-paragraphs';
}
}`
But it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The answer posted by kiamlaluno should work, use that.